# Vnc bandwidth to quality & compression level

Tags: linux, bandwidth, vnc

what quality and compression level would you recommend for 128 KB/s upload on server side ? I tried all reasonable combinations but I can't decide because I don't know what bandwidth approximately the server needs for sending jpegs to client. And how much is needed for -nojpeg option ?

Using tigervnc now...

Thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend more bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Tight encoding, maximum compression level (which is 9 in TightVNC-compatible viewers), and JPEG quality level 6. That should work but updates may go slowly as bandwidth is quite low.

Using -nojpeg option may increase bandwidth requirements (up to 10 times if photo-like graphics would be transmitted, less otherwise).

Constantin
tightvnc.com

Comment: Thank you Constantin, I've already asked my ISP to upgrade my tariff :-) Btw I'm using a custom GTK theme for eclipse IDE (small font size especially for laptop use). Could you please tell me how to reflect this into the remote session ? Because whatever GTK application I start via vncviewer it has the local GTK settings.